# psql not found in script for trying to control startup and shutdown order in Docker Compose

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make sure my Django app waits for my Postgres db to start so I don't get this error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: the database system is starting up`, I've read this https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/, and here is what I have so far

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db", "bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`wait-for-it.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-it.sh

set -e
  
host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"
  
# postgres

until PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
  
>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine3.14
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-libs && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY . /code/
RUN chmod u+x ./wait-for-it.sh
```

EDIT #1:
This is my directory structure
Root directory
[image]
Backend directory
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine several different solutions.

First of all, if you use `pg_isready`, you don't need any custom `wait-for-it.sh` scripts because `pg_isready` works great. So just remove your `wait-for-it.sh` file.

Also if you use `healthcheck` in the `docker-compose.yml`, you don't need to run any check scripts manually before running your `entrypoint.sh`. But you need to add condition to `depends_on` section. So change your `docker-compose.yml` to the following:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DB_USER}"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Be aware, I also changed `test` command in `healthcheck` section and removed first `command` in `backend` image.

Comment: I get the same error, and now it says for my db `db_1       | 2021-08-27 16:33:06.337 UTC [51] FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: I have looked deeply in to your problem, and updated my answer.

Comment: Where should my `entrypoint.sh` be placed, I currently have it in the same level as my `docker-compose.yml`. I've run `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` to make sure I can run it as an executable

Comment: No it doesn't, I get this error `Recreating 2746a8f900d2_scrapytutorial_backend_1 ... error

ERROR: for 2746a8f900d2_scrapytutorial_backend_1  Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for backend  Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: That means you don't have entrypoint.sh in your root(backend) directory. Are you sure you placed it? It should be in the same directory where you placed requirements.txt.

Comment: I've updated my post, how would I then in the future use a frontend which is in its own directory for docker-compose. I only have docker-compose.yml in my root directory and I have a backend directory which contains the backend code, requirements.txt and entrypoint.sh now.